# Vigenere cipher C program

Tags: c, vigenere-cipher, encryption

I implemented a Vigenere cipher that preserves case and can also decrypt if you pass the `-d` argument. Usage is `./vigenere <plaintext|ciphertext> key [-d]` and it works fine but I think there are probably some things I could do better. So, just looking for critique.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ENCRYPT 1
#define DECRYPT -1

int mod(int x, int n)
{
    return (x % n + n) % n;
}

char *vigenere(char *input, char *keystream, int mode)
{
    if (strlen(keystream) != strlen(input))
        return NULL;
    
    int output_len = strlen(input), offset = 'a', wasupper = 0; 
    char *output = malloc(output_len);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < output_len; ++i)
    {
        if (isupper(input[i]))
        {
            input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
            wasupper = 1;
        }
        else
            wasupper = 0;
            
        output[i] = mod((input[i] - offset) + (keystream[i] - offset) * mode, 26) + offset;
        
        if (wasupper)
            output[i] = toupper(output[i]);
    }

    return output;
}

char *gen_keystream(char *key, int keystream_len)
{
    int key_len = strlen(key), j = 0;
    char *keystream = malloc(keystream_len);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < keystream_len; j = ++i % key_len)
        keystream[i] = key[j];
        
    return keystream;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc < 3)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
        
    int mode = ENCRYPT;
        
    if (argc > 3 && strcmp(argv[3], "-d") == 0)
        mode = DECRYPT;
        
    int keystream_len = strlen(argv[1]);
    char *keystream = gen_keystream(argv[2], keystream_len);
    char *result = vigenere(argv[1], keystream, mode);
    
    printf("%s\n", result);

    free(keystream);
    free(result);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

## Process a stream of data instead of a single string

Your program works by passing the input as a command-line argument, but what if you want to encode or decode a whole file? What if the input is huge? I would try to modify the program so that it can run from a file, or from standard input if no file is specified, so you can do for example:

```
./vigenere key < plaintext.txt > ciphertext.txt
```

Answer (score 7):

**Bug: no null character**

`printf("%s\n", result);` fails as `result` does not point to a *string*.  That data lacks a *null character* and is short, by 1 of allocated memory needed.

```
// char *output = malloc(output_len);
char *output = malloc(output_len +1);
output[output_len] = '\0';
```

Similar problem with decryptor.

**No protection against non-A-Z characters**

I'd expect only encrypting/decrypting when the `input[]` is an `A-Z`.

I suspect code may generate `output[i] == 0` for select inputs, rendering the string short.

---

**Pedantic bug: Negative `char`**

When `input[i] < 0`, `isupper(input[i])` is UB.  Better to access the string via an `unsigned char *` for `is...()`.

A negative `char` value also messes-up `mod()`.  When `x < 0`, `x % n` code does [*not*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20638659/2410359) perform a Euclidean mod.

Comment: In your code example you comment out the first line, then repeat it verbatim - shouldn't your replacement  be `char *output = malloc(output_len)+1;` ?

Comment: @GuntramBlohm You mean `char *output = malloc(output_len + 1);`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ouch. Got me.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I first used the transparent no width `+ 1`.  Edited to show opaque code`.  (IOWs, I erred)

Comment: As part of the comment about negative `char`, the program doesn't play well with letters such as `à` or `ñ`, even if converted to unsigned first...

Answer (score 6):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Always use braces

The code currently includes this:

```
if (isupper(input[i]))
{
    input[i] = tolower(input[i]);
    wasupper = 1;
}
else
    wasupper = 0;

    output[i] = mod((input[i] - offset) + (keystream[i] - offset) * mode, 26) + offset;
    
    if (wasupper)
        output[i] = toupper(output[i]);
```

The problem is that the indentation after the `else` *suggests* that all of those lines are executed only if `isupper(input[i])` evaluates to false, but that's not the case.  Only the `wasupper = 0;` line is exclusively executed on that path.  So then the reader of the code has to try to figure out if it's an indentation error or a missing braces error.  For that reason, especially if you're new to the language, I recommend *always* using `{}` for such conditional constructs.

### Fix the bugs

A string in C must be terminated with a `'\0'` character to be able to use function calls such as `strlen()`, but there are bugs in `gen_keystream` and in `vigenere` that fail to account for the terminator.  Remember that `strlen()` returns the length of a string *excluding* this terminating character.

### Think carefully about mathematical operations

This function is not broken, but it's not as efficient as it could be:

```
int mod(int x, int n)
{
    return (x % n + n) % n;
}
```

We can express the same notion using simply `return (x + n) % n;` given the expected range of `x` is \$(-n,n)\$.  You can also simplify a bit more than this, as I'll demonstrate later.

### Use `const` where practical

Because `vigenere` should alter neither `input` nor `keystream`, both should be declared `const`.

### Put each statement on a single line

It is detrimental to the readability of your code declare several variables on the same line or to abuse the comma operator:

```
int output_len = strlen(input), offset = 'a', wasupper = 0;
```

Instead, separating each statement on its own line makes the code easier to read and maintain.  See [ES.10](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration)

### Check return values for errors

Calls to `malloc` can fail.  You must check the return values to make sure they haven't or your program may crash (or worse) when given malformed input or due to low system resources.  Rigorous error handling is the difference between mostly working versus bug-free software.  You should strive for the latter.

### Consider whether a function is needed

There are other ways to structure the program so that neither `gen_keystream` nor `keystream` are needed.  You could simply pass the key into a modified version of `vigenere`.

### Consider using pointers instead of indexing

Using pointers effectively is an essential skill for every C programmer.  Here's a rewritten version of your function using most of the simplifications and corrections mentioned above:

```
char *vigenere(const char *input, const char *key, int mode)
{
    int output_len = strlen(input); 
    if (output_len == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    // add +1 for the terminating NUL character
    char *output = malloc(output_len + 1);
    if (output == NULL) {
        return output;
    }
    const char *keyptr = key;
    output[output_len] = '\0';
    
    for (char *curr = output ; *input; ++input) {
        if (*keyptr == '\0') {
            keyptr = key;
        }
        *curr = (mode * (*keyptr - tolower(*input)) + 26) % 26 + 'a';
        if (isupper(*input)) {
            *curr = toupper(*curr);
        }
        ++curr;
        ++keyptr;
    }
    return output;
}
```

Note that in this code, I assume that all characters have already been checked and `isalpha()` is true for all input and that `islower()` and `isalpha()` are both true for every character of the key.

Comment: Nitpick: Commas between variable declarations are not the "comma operator". And it's quite common and ideomatic to initialize multiple variables on a single line.

Comment: True, it's not the comma operator in this context, but while it was once common to do so, modern usage favors one declaration per line.  I've updated my answer to clarify this point.

Answer (score 1):

## This isn't a Vignère cipher

This line:

> ```
> if (strlen(keystream) != strlen(input))
>     return NULL;
> ```

means that the key needs to be exactly the same length as the input.  So what you really have is a one-time-pad.

A real Vignère cipher, in contrast, can encode arbitrarily large messages, by re-using the key every `strlen(key)` input characters.  This explains how a Vignère cipher is less secure than OTP, particularly for short keys - but it's much more usable.

Comment: You might want to double check that.  The code does, in fact, work with long input.

Comment: Oh, I see - the calling code repeats the key.  The function is still poorly named, IMO.  And it shouldn't be necessary to allocate memory and copy out the key - I'll leave eliminating that as an exercise for the question author.